# Por que "echo" aceita parênteses no PHP?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem, sintaxe

No PHP, o `echo` pode receber parênteses porque considera isso uma expressão? Aparentemente, alguns recursos da linguagem parecem não serem padronizados e, por isso, podem ser utilizados de inúmeras maneiras.

Por exemplo:

```
echo ('teste');
```

Ou então:

```
echo ('teste1'), ('teste2');
```

Gostaria de saber o porquê disso ser aceito e o motivo do `echo` aceitar vírgulas. Também gostaria de saber se `echo` é ou não uma construção de linguagem, pois a documentação diz o seguinte:

> echo não é uma função atualmente (construtor da linguagem) então não é obrigatório usar parênteses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é o `echo` que aceita parênteses, o que ocorre é que tudo que vem **depois** do `echo` **com** ou **sem** parênteses serão entendidos como valores, por exemplo uma ou mais strings ou valores ou variáveis que podem ser "printadas")

Tanto que `echo` suporta múltiplos valores, por exemplo:

```
echo 'a', 'b', 'c';
```

ou:

```
echo ('a'), ('b'), ('c');
```

Já se fizesse isso iria falhar:

```
echo ('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Causando o erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','

Isto funciona desta forma porque `echo` não é uma função, mas sim um *construtor de linguagem*.

Eu acho esse termo meio estranho, conforme a documentação, mas entendo que isto quer dizer que o `echo` é algo "natural" na linguagem PHP, como se fosse `if`, `else`, `break`, etc. Ou seja `echo` é parte da linguagem e se comporta conforme necessário e de fato não pode pode ser executado como uma função.

Agora entendendo os parênteses, em PHP (e até na maioria das linguagens) eles são usados para "isolar" certas operações, tipo uma operação matemática em PHP assim iria retornar um valor:

```
$foo = 20 + 8 * 2; // 36
echo $foo;
```

Já assim seria outro:

```
$foo = (20 + 8) * 2; // 56
echo $foo;
```

Ou seja o `echo` ou até mesmo atribuir uma variável (`$foo =`) não enxergam os parênteses, a linguagem em si avalia isto antes e os parênteses são usados para separar operações necessárias, como por exemplo operações matemáticas

Resumindo, fazer isso `echo ('foo');` seria quase equivalente a fazer isto:

```
$a = ('foo');
echo $a;
```

Pois os parênteses não são parte do `echo`.

Answer (score 5):

A pergunta já responde. PHP é uma linguagem sem muito critério. Ela foi criada por quem não entende teoria de linguagens e vai fazendo na necessidade (nem dá para falar em intuitividade porque o intuitivo é o padrão). E quem cria a linguagem pode fazer do jeito que bem entender, inclusive sem ter que explicar para ninguém porque foi feito daquele jeito, ainda que faça a linguagem perder credibilidade entre bons profissionais de desenvolvimento.

Podemos ver `echo` de duas formas: uma construção de linguagem, já que aceita sem parênteses, portanto ela é especial, não é uma função comum; ou podemos ver como uma função, que é inerentemente uma expressão sempre, e a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) ajuda remeter a esta tese, mesmo que indique não ser. No fim ficou uma confusão entre uma coisa e outra. Pelo fato de resultar sempre em `void` faz pouco sentido usar `echo` como expressão.

E o que você passa como parâmetro pode ser qualquer expressão que possa ser convertida para o tipo *string*.

O fato de poder ou não ter parênteses é uma decisão do criador da linguagem. Eu faria isto ser uma função comum com obrigatoriedade de deles. Mas se quiser mesmo fazer ser construção de linguagem eu não permitira o seu uso em condições normais para deixar claro que é uma construção e não uma função, embora seja um pouco complicado, mas não impossível, proibir os parênteses de uma expressão como outra qualquer.

Não está claro sobre o que estes parênteses se referem, e na prática pouco importa, mas eu diria que eles fazem parte da construção e não uma expressão, até porque em expressões os parênteses em caso assim são desnecessários, então não faria sentido documentar. Mas novamente, é uma especulação de alguém que estuda linguagens. Pelo menos no primeiro exemplo. No segundo é claramente de expressão, porque os parênteses da construção só pode conter toda expressão a ser ecoada, o fato de ter 2 tira a ambiguidade da interpretação.

A construção aceita vírgulas porque foi definido que iria aceitar. Faz sentido pode ter várias expressões e ele lidar com isso e coar todas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).